# Append react component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to add dynamically react components into other react component when I press a button, rigth now I'm doing that using jQuery but the code is Awful. The principal idea is when I press 
 `<Button onClick={this.addProcess} data-mode="Hadoop"><Icon name="plus"/></Button>`
a the process will be attached in the server. this is handle by `onClick={this.addProcess}` that has all the logic to does it.

My code using Jquery:

```
var React = require('react');
var ReactDOM = require('react-dom');
var {Icon} = require('react-fa');
var moment = require('moment');
var TimeAgo = require('react-timeago')

var {
    ButtonGroup,
    DropdownButton,
    MenuItem,
    Button,
    Grid,
    Row,
    Col
} = require('react-bootstrap');

var ServerCanvas = React.createClass({
        addProcess: function(event) {
    // console.log(event.currentTarget.dataset.mode)


    var process = event.currentTarget.dataset.mode;
    var processDiv;

    switch (process) {
        case "Hadoop":
            processDiv = ` <div class="Grid-cell Grid" style="flex-flow: column nowrap; background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(244, 143, 177) 0%, rgb(194, 24, 91) 100%);">
            <div class="Grid-cell" style="font-size: 150%;">Hd</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell" style="font-size: 75%;">Hadoop</div>
            <div class="Grid-cell" style="font-size: 75%; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
            </div>
          </div>`;
            break;
        default:

    }

    var server = $('#servers').find('.test').not('.complete').first();

    if (server.children().length < 3) {

        server.append(processDiv); ///Append the new process

        if (server.first().children().length === 3) {
            server.addClass('complete');
        }
    }
},

    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="">
                <Grid className="no-margin-padding container-hack">
                    <Row>
                        <Col md={4} className='grey-box'>
                            <Row className="rowHeight">
                                <Col md={6} className='text-center rowButton_Mid_Height'>
                                    <div className="pull-right">
                                        <Button bsClass='btn btn-default btn-lg btn-round' onClick={this.addServer}><Icon name="plus"/></Button>
                                        <div>Add server</div>
                                    </div>
                                </Col>
                                <Col md={6} className='text-center rowButton_Mid_Height'>
                                    <div className="pull-left">
                                        <Button bsClass='btn btn-default btn-lg btn-round' onClick={this.removeServer}><Icon name="minus"/></Button>
                                        <div>Destroy Server</div>
                                    </div>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>

                        </Col>
                        <Col md={8} className='black-box'>
                            <h1>Server Canvas</h1>
                            <div id='servers' className="serverContainer">
                                <div className="test grey-box">
                                    <div className='text-center'>Server 0</div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                    <Row>
                        <Col xs={4} md={4} className=''>
                            <Row>
                                <Col xs={12} md={12} className=''>
                                    <div>
                                        <div className='HadoopBackground pull-left'>
                                            &nbsp;
                                        </div>
                                        Hadoop
                                        <div className='pull-right'>
                                            <Button bsClass='btn btn-default btn-xs btn-round HadoopBackgroundButton'><Icon name="minus"/></Button>
                                            <Button bsClass='btn btn-default btn-xs btn-round HadoopBackgroundButton' onClick={this.addProcess} data-mode="Hadoop"><Icon name="plus"/></Button>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </Col>
                            </Row>
                        </Col>
                    </Row>
                </Grid>
            </div>
        )
    }
});

ReactDOM.render(
    <ServerCanvas/>, document.getElementById('app'));
```

But that I'm looking for is create other react component (named Process in the code below) and When I press the button and `addProcess` is fired insert the Process component  (Some code was removed):

```
var Process = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div className="Grid-cell Grid">
      <div className="Grid-cell" >Hd</div>
      <div className="Grid-cell" >Hadoop</div>
      <div><time className='loaded timeago'></time></div>
      <div className="Grid-cell" >
      </div>
    </div>
    );
  }
})


addProcess: function(event) {
    // console.log(event.currentTarget.dataset.mode)


    var process = event.currentTarget.dataset.mode;
    var processDiv;

    var server = $('#servers').find('.test').not('.complete').first();

    if (server.children().length < 3) {
        console.log('puedo crear hijos');
          server.append(<Process />); //Add the new process but nothing happend.


        if (server.first().children().length === 3) {
            server.addClass('complete');
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a small adjustment to represent the current servers as an array in state, you can just iterate over all servers that have been added. Here is a stripped down version to demonstrate how you might go about that:

```
var ServerCanvas = React.createClass({
    // represent servers in state
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            servers: []
        }
    },
    // add new server to state
    addService: function(event) {
        this.setState({
            servers: this.state.servers.concat(event.currentTarget.dataset.mode)
        });
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <h3>Servers</h3>
                <div className="servers">
                    {this.state.servers.map(function(server) {
                        return (
                            <div className="Grid-cell Grid" style="flex-flow: column nowrap; background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(244, 143, 177) 0%, rgb(194, 24, 91) 100%);">
                                <div class="Grid-cell" style="font-size: 75%;">{server}</div>
                                <div class="Grid-cell" style="font-size: 75%; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                                </div>
                           </div>
                        )
                    })}
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
})
```

You could also split the Server into its own component:

```
var Server = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div className="Grid-cell Grid" style="flex-flow: column nowrap; background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgb(244, 143, 177) 0%, rgb(194, 24, 91) 100%);">
                <div class="Grid-cell" style="font-size: 75%;">{this.props.serviceName}</div>
                <div class="Grid-cell" style="font-size: 75%; color: rgb(0, 0, 0);">
                </div>
           </div>
        )
    }
})
```

and change `ServerCanvas` render to:

```
{this.state.servers.map(function(server) {
    return <Server serviceName={server} />;
})}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create a separated component and import it in your file, something like a ProcessComponent.

To add multiple stances of it, you should have an array of this components in your state, so when you need to add another you just push a value to this array you have in the State and use setState to handle render and update.

Something like this on render:

```
render() {
    var self = this;
    //This "self" here is because inside the loop below, the "this" context is going to be Jquery and not your Class. So you keep it in a separated value just for refence purpose. Like passing a callBack as in the example.
    var processComponent = this.state.processOnState.map(function(item, i) 
    {
        return (
                <Process key={"process"+i} ref={"process"+i} anyCallback={self.callBackMethodForParent.bind(self)} dataForProcess={item.dataToComponent} />
                );
    }.bind(this));
return (
 <div>
      <Col md={8} className='black-box'>
           <h1>Server Canvas</h1>
           <div id='servers' className="serverContainer">
                <div className="test grey-box">
                     <div className='text-center'>Server 0</div>
                 </div>
                 {processComponent}
           </div>
      </Col>
 </div>
)
```

So once you update the data you can trigger an update by using:

```
setState({processOnState:[{dataToComponent:1},{dataToComponent:2}]})
```

By default react should always handle all the render and updates, it has a logic that runs throught the DOM and finds out what has changed, and then just re-render it. You can trigger this behavior by using setState, thats the point.

Ref: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/component-api.html#setstate